# PHP - Insert into mysql database from form with the help of loops, is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, loops, phpmyadmin

Alright, so i'm sitting here messing around with some old code I had.

Below is an example of a loop i run to print out the products and the current stock.
Whenever i want to change this manually i will open this and enter the new stock value.
But I'm stuck, For some reason i cannot get it to insert at the right ProdId in the DB.

```
// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $oneLiter )) {
                        echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'<?php echo $row['ProdId']; ?>'"/>'
                        // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo '<td>' . $row['Prodnamn'] . '<div class="min_lager">' . $row['minLager'] . '</div></td>';
                        echo '<td><input class="lager" type="number" name="prod['. $row['ProdId'] .']" value="' . $row['Lagerstatus'] . '"></td>';
                        echo "</tr>"; 
                    } 

                    // close table>
                    echo "</table>";
```

This is the following code from my try at inserting the value that I've changed.

```
// check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {

 // get form data, making sure it is valid
    foreach($_POST['prod'] as $item) {
        $stock = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($item));
     // check that prodname/color fields are both filled in
     if ($stock == '')
     {
     // generate error message
     $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

     //error, display form
     renderForm($id, $prodname, $color, $size, $packing, $minstock, $stock, $error);
     }
     else
         {
         // save the data to the database
         mysql_query("UPDATE produkter_sthlm SET Lagerstatus='$stock' WHERE ProdId='$item'") 
         or die(mysql_error());
         // once saved, redirect back to the view page
         header("Location: lagerstatus_stockholm.php");
         }
     } 
 }
 else
 // if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form
 {

 // query db
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produkter_sthlm")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 // check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
 if($row)
 {

 // get data from db
 $id = $row['ProdId'];
 $prodname = $row['Prodnamn'];
 $color = $row['Farg'];
 $size = $row['Storlek'];
 $packing = $row['antalPack'];
 $minstock = $row['minLager'];
 $stock = $row['Lagerstatus'];

 // show form
 renderForm($id, $prodname, $color, $size, $packing, $minstock, $stock, '');
 }
 else
 // if no match, display result
 {
 echo "No results!";
 }
 }
```

I know that  **mysql_query("UPDATE produkter_sthlm SET Lagerstatus='$stock' WHERE ProdId='$item'")** is wrong but i cannot figure it out how to get the real ProdId from the $_POST

I can post complete files with schema copies etc if it is to any help.

Just edited in the entire file.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
    header("location:login.php");
}
// connect to the database
include '/include/config.php';

function renderForm($id, $prodname, $color, $size, $packing, $minstock, $stock, $error)
 {
 $oneLiter = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produkter_sthlm WHERE `Storlek`=1 AND `Active`=1") or die(mysql_error());
$fourLiter = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produkter_sthlm WHERE `Storlek`=4 AND `Active`=1") or die(mysql_error());
$fiveLiter = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produkter_sthlm WHERE `Storlek`=5 AND `Active`=1") or die(mysql_error());
$tenLiter = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produkter_sthlm WHERE `Storlek`=10 AND `Active`=1") or die(mysql_error());
$twentyLiter = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produkter_sthlm WHERE `Storlek`=20 AND `Active`=1") or die(mysql_error());
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Lagerstatus Stockholm - Petrolia Lagersystem</title>

    <!-- Core CSS - Include with every page -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom-style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Page-Level Plugin CSS - Blank -->

    <!-- SB Admin CSS - Include with every page -->
    <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <?php include "top_menu.php"; ?>
        <?php include "side_menu.php"; ?>

        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <h1 class="page-header">Lagerstatus - Stockholm <?php print(Date("F j, Y H:i:s")); ?></h1>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="button-container">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save fa-fw"></i>Spara ändring</button> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 well">                    
                        <h2 class="horizontal">1 Liter</h2>
                        <?php echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
                        echo "<tr><th>Typ</th> <th>Antal</th></tr>";

                        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $oneLiter )) {
                            echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['ProdId'].'"/>';
                            // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo '<td>' . $row['Prodnamn'] . '<div class="min_lager">' . $row['minLager'] . '</div></td>';
                            echo '<td><input class="lager" type="number" name="prod['. $row['ProdId'] .']" value="' . $row['Lagerstatus'] . '"></td>';
                            echo "</tr>"; 
                        } 

                        // close table>
                        echo "</table>";
                    ?>

                        <h2 class="horizontal">4 Liter</h2>
                        <?php echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
                        echo "<tr><th>Typ</th> <th>Antal</th></tr>";

                        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $fourLiter )) {

                            // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo '<td>' . $row['Prodnamn'] . '<div class="min_lager">' . $row['minLager'] . '</div></td>';
                            echo '<td><input class="lager" type="number" name="prod['. $row['ProdId'] .']" value="' . $row['Lagerstatus'] . '"></td>';
                            echo "</tr>"; 
                        } 

                        // close table>
                        echo "</table>";
                    ?>
                    </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                <div class="col-md-6 well">
                    <h2 class="horizontal">5 Liter</h2>
                        <?php echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
                        echo "<tr><th>Typ</th> <th>Antal</th></tr>";

                        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $fiveLiter )) {

                            // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo '<td>' . $row['Prodnamn'] . '<div class="min_lager">' . $row['minLager'] . '</div></td>';
                            echo '<td><input class="lager" type="number" name="prod['. $row['ProdId'] .']" value="' . $row['Lagerstatus'] . '"></td>';
                            echo "</tr>"; 
                        } 

                        // close table>
                        echo "</table>";
                    ?>

                    <h2 class="horizontal">10 Liter</h2>
                        <?php echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
                        echo "<tr><th>Typ</th> <th>Antal</th></tr>";

                        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $tenLiter )) {

                            // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo '<td>' . $row['Prodnamn'] . '<div class="min_lager">' . $row['minLager'] . '</div></td>';
                            echo '<td><input class="lager" type="number" name="prod['. $row['ProdId'] .']" value="' . $row['Lagerstatus'] . '"></td>';
                            echo "</tr>"; 
                        } 

                        // close table>
                        echo "</table>";
                    ?>

                    <h2 class="horizontal">20 Liter</h2>
                        <?php echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
                        echo "<tr><th>Typ</th> <th>Antal</th></tr>";

                        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $twentyLiter )) {

                            // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo '<td>' . $row['Prodnamn'] . '<div class="min_lager">' . $row['minLager'] . '</div></td>';
                            echo '<td><input class="lager" type="number" name="prod['. $row['ProdId'] .']" value="' . $row['Lagerstatus'] . '"></td>';
                            echo "</tr>"; 
                        } 

                        // close table>
                        echo "</table>";
                    ?>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- Core Scripts - Include with every page -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>

    <!-- Page-Level Plugin Scripts - Blank -->

    <!-- SB Admin Scripts - Include with every page -->
    <script src="js/sb-admin.js"></script>

    <!-- Page-Level Demo Scripts - Blank - Use for reference -->

</body>

</html>
<?php
 }


 // check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {

 // get form data, making sure it is valid
    foreach($_POST['prod'] as $item) {
        $stock = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($item));
     // check that prodname/color fields are both filled in
     if ($stock == '')
     {
     // generate error message
     $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

     //error, display form
     renderForm($id, $prodname, $color, $size, $packing, $minstock, $stock, $error);
     }
     else
         {
         echo "lol" . $_POST['prod'];
         // save the data to the database
         mysql_query("UPDATE produkter_sthlm SET Lagerstatus='$stock' WHERE ProdId='$item'") 
         or die(mysql_error());
         // once saved, redirect back to the view page
         header("Location: lagerstatus_stockholm.php");
         }
     } 
 }
 else
 // if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form
 {

 // query db
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produkter_sthlm")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 // check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
 if($row)
 {

 // get data from db
 $id = $row['ProdId'];
 $prodname = $row['Prodnamn'];
 $color = $row['Farg'];
 $size = $row['Storlek'];
 $packing = $row['antalPack'];
 $minstock = $row['minLager'];
 $stock = $row['Lagerstatus'];

 // show form
 renderForm($id, $prodname, $color, $size, $packing, $minstock, $stock, '');
 }
 else
 // if no match, display result
 {
 echo "No results!";
 }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Try dumping the $_POST data to see what you are passing. var_dump($_POST); or in your loop even var_dump($item);

Comment: This line: mysql_query("UPDATE produkter_sthlm SET Lagerstatus='$stock' WHERE ProdId='$item'") here i have to replace $item with the ProdId that is somehow generated by the while loop further up. This is my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third line of the first script (including the comment):

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'<?php echo $row['ProdId']; ?>'"/>'
```

is missing a semicolon at the end. It also is echoed for each iteration of the while loop, which will cause `$_POST['id']` to always contain the value of the last 'hidden' input tag on the page.

My suggestion would be to create two arrays of input data, using generated keys:

```
// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $oneLiter )) {
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'<?php echo $row['ProdId']; ?>'"/>';
    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['Prodnamn'] . '<div class="min_lager">' . $row['minLager'] . '</div></td>';
    echo '<td><input class="lager" type="number" name="status[]" value="' . $row['Lagerstatus'] . '"></td>';
    echo "</tr>"; 
}

// close table>
echo "</table>";
```

Then you can loop through the results as follows. As the hidden inputs and number inputs are rendered in pairs, the keys to the respective POST arrays will match:

```
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $prodId) {
    // As both seem to be integers, SQL injections can easily be filtered out by explicitly casting it to an integer
    $prodId = (int) $prodId;

    if ($prodId > 0) {
        $prodStatus = (int) $_POST['status'][$key];

        // do your processing here
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to hear, didn't test it. ;)

Comment: Althto i have a move complex problem on another page of the same site, instead of just have 1 input per product, i have 2 fields, 1 produced and 1 delivered. after all products are listed there is another form with questions about cleaning the production room etc. How should i take on this, since it is both text and ints.

Comment: Take the same approach, use inputs with names like "produced[]" and "delivered[]". If the values could be both strings and integers, just use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) instead of `(int)` as SQL injection filtering. Works on both integers and string. The other form inputs can be handled any way you like after the foreach loop.